# Display random image when refresh

Tags: image, random, refresh

I am trying to figure out how to use the code posted by Nicholas Lim in [Random images on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913479/random-images-on-click) to display random post when page refreshes.

I am using wordpress for my website, the url structure does not contain .php extension. So i won't be able to use it to display random image in my WP post, am i right?

If it is possible, could anyone please guide me step by step how to use the code.

I spent much time reading about this, but still haven't understood.

Thank you in advanced

Comment: So have you tried to write any code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure what your requirements are here.

Is this correct:
1. You want to display random images on a page refresh.
2. You're not running a php server.

If yes to both of the above, then why not just use the JavaScript example from the post that you have included in your original question?

Comment: Hi user1367351. Thank you very much for your suggestion. I'm running website on a shared server. WP by default requires php, right? So definitely it is a php server, right? Sorry i'm not a techical person. Actually i don't know what the-img-id is, so i don't know how to change it to apply to my case. <br> To use the javascript on that reference, do i really need to change "the-image-id" parameter?

Comment: And also, i know how to echo a php function in my ubuntu, but don't know how it comes to the web-page.

Comment: For example, to use a php function, we must create a php file and put the code in the file, then gp to browser and type the php file into the address bar. But when i want to display image in a WP post/page, the url structure does not have .php extension. So i'm confused. Have you seen my problem?

Comment: The simplest solution is usually the most appropriate.  Have a look at this: http://www.robwalshonline.com//jquery_plugins/randomImage/jquery.robwalsh.randomImageOnload.js  JavaScript has a low barrier of entry and if you're not a techie, then you'll probably want the bar low.  In this example all you need do is change the list of images and define an image tag on your web page.  Hope this helps.